# MySQL function if elseif 1064

Tags: mysql, function, if-statement

I'm trying to use MySQL but since 2 days I'm stuck on it.
I've got an 1064 error which mean syntax error. I tried a lot of things but none worked.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION set_libelle(civilite VARCHAR(4), prenom VARCHAR(30), nom VARCHAR(30)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(20) 
    BEGIN
        IF (LEN(civilite)+LEN(prenom)+LEN(nom)<19) THEN
            RETURN civilite + ' ' + prenom + ' ' + nom;
        ELSEIF (LEN(civilite)+LEN(nom)<17) THEN 
            RETURN civilite + ' ' + LEFT(prenom,1) + '. ' + nom;
        ELSE 
            RETURN civilite + ' ' + LEFT(prenom,1) + '. ' + LEFT(nom, (17-(LEN(civilite)));
        END IF;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Have you got an idea why this doesn't work ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `+` for string concatenation rather than `concat()`.

The proper syntax is:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION set_libelle(civilite VARCHAR(4), prenom VARCHAR(30), nom VARCHAR(30)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(20) 
    BEGIN
        IF (LEN(civilite) + LEN(prenom) + LEN(nom) < 19) THEN
            RETURN CONCAT_WS(' ', civilite,  prenom, ',', nom);
        ELSEIF (LEN(civilite) + LEN(nom) < 17) THEN 
            RETURN CONCAT_WS(' ', civilite, LEFT(prenom, 1), '.', nom);
        ELSE 
            RETURN CONCAT_WS(' ', civilite, LEFT(prenom, 1), '.', LEFT(nom, 17 - LEN(civilite)) );
        END IF;
    END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/94d45b) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: It might help, but it didn't sove problem : I've still have error : "1064 (42000) [...] right syntax to use near ';
END IF;
END' at line 9

Comment: @Thibaud.P . . . The edits look right to me now, but it is not working in SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Still not good. I'm using MySQL.
In your edit, I should remove DELIMITER at top ?

Comment: @Thibaud.P . . . SQL FIddle treats delimiters differently from code.  You should have the delimiter statement.